# why UIBarButtonItem default is disable?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have two projects.
I created one UIBarButtonItem object on the first project. It's enabled by default but in the other project it's disabled by default.

[image]

I am using iOS6, Xcode.4.6.1
I see the same result in iOS5 ,iOS4. UIBarButtonItem default value is enabled.
Why ? Global setting? Project setting?

Comment: Post both please if you are wanting a comparison. More than likely it's exactly what @Artur has described. In your example there is no action set.

Comment: Is "User Interaction Enabled" selected for the tool bar (if you created it in IB that is)?

Answer (score 0):

In your other project you probably did set target and action. In Cocoa, button that has no target or action is considered disabled.

Comment: like this    { target:self action:@selector(backto_nearme_user)] } The problem is still the same

Comment: @user993077 Hmm... Sorry then, I just supposed that, wasn't sure.

Comment: I don't think this is true. If you add a toolbar to a view, and run the app, the default button responds to clicking by changing its color -- it's not disabled, despite having no action.